# firebase I want to retrieve primary key

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image][image]
I can pull data from the yellow edge, but I can't pull it back from the red edge. This is my code example[!

I can pull data from the yellow edge, but I can't pull it back from the red edge. This is my code example[! extract the primary key and display it.`

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s.